# Modeling data from Excel sheets to parse to Excel sheet

Tags: object-oriented, vba, excel, hash-map

#### Background:

I have close to 50 excel files - I cannot change the data source - and I steadily get more.
My task is to make sense of all that data and, lo an behold, save that as another excel file (I asked if I should put it in a local database, but no, I should not).

*Asking on SO lead me here, as I thought it might be a better fit here, but my problem, if it even is one, is quite specific.*

---

#### Code:

In my current code I used a couple of classes to model the data; I read somewhere that data should be data and not a class but are dictionaries helpful in this case?

Assembly Class:

```vb
Private pPartnumber As String
Private pDescription As String
Private pLevel As Long
Private pSupplier As Supplier
Private pCustomers As CustomerCollection
Private pSubAssemblies As AssemblyCollection
Private pWarehouse As String
Private pEligibility As String
Private pApprovedData As String
Private pApprovedDataBasedOn As String
Private BuyOrMake As AssemblyBuyMake
Public Enum AssemblyBuyMake
    Buy = 0
    Make = 1
    Both = 2
    Other = 4
End Enum
' Lots of getters and setters
' removed for conciseness

Private Sub SetEligibilityOfSubAssemblies(ByVal Value As String)
    Dim subAssembly As Assembly
    If Not pSubAssemblies Is Nothing Then
        For Each subAssembly In pSubAssemblies
            subAssembly.Eligibility = Value
        Next
    End If
End Sub
Private Sub SetApprovedDataOfSubAssemblies(ByVal Value As String)
    Dim subAssembly As Assembly
    If Not pSubAssemblies Is Nothing Then
        For Each subAssembly In pSubAssemblies
            subAssembly.ApprovedData = Value
        Next
    End If
End Sub

'@Description "Checks if Partnumbers are equal, ignores Description- and other deviations"
Public Function Equals(ByVal Assembly As Assembly) As Boolean
    Equals = (pPartnumber = Assembly.Partnumber)
End Function
```

As you can see my class has lots of fields; the two setter subs are private as any Subassembly automatically inherits the Topassembly's ApprovedData and Eligibility as per requirement.

AssemblyCollection:

```vb
Private pAssemblyCollection As Collection
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pAssemblyCollection = New Collection
End Sub
Public Sub Add(ByVal Value As Assembly, Optional ByVal Key As String)
    '
End Sub
Public Sub Remove(Optional ByVal Value As Assembly, Optional ByVal Key As String)
    '
End Sub

'@DefaultMember
Public Function Item(Optional ByVal index As Long = -1, Optional ByVal Key As String) As Assembly
    '
End Function

'@MemberAttribute VB_MemberFlags, "40"
'@Enumerator
Public Property Get NewEnum() As IUnknown
    Set NewEnum = pAssemblyCollection.[_NewEnum]
End Property
```

The `CustomerCollection` looks the same.

Customer:

```vb
Private pName As String
Private pID As String
Private pCountry As String
Private pHTSCode As String
' And its getters and setters

'@Description "Returns True if Name, ID and HTSCode are the same"
Public Function Equals(ByVal Customer As Customer) As Boolean
    Equals = (pName = Customer.Name And pID = Customer.ID And pHTSCode = Customer.HTSCode)
End Function
```

The `HTSCode` is currently part of the `Customer` as the file I found it in contains Customer and sales data and barely enough assembly data to identify an assembly - think "customer has a partnumber for an assembly and my files have a partnumber which don't match" and you are just supposed to know which ones refer to the same assembly.

---

#### Question:

Instead of using these classes should I use dictionaries of dictionaries?
And for comparing data of different sheets should I store either these classes or dictionaries with the data in new dictionaries or arrays?
I'm not sure if there's a maximum on how many custom objects I can create (other than memory limits), but I fear I'll end up with a lot of `Assembly` instances in this case.

*Currently I*

```vb
Dim arr() As Assembly
```

*to collect all the data before parsing it to a sheet.*

Comment: In VBA, collection objects (collections, array lists, scripting.dictionaries) don't restrict the type of data used as a key or value as they are based on the Variant datatype under the hood.  A good practice in VBA is to wrap a collection object so that the getters and setters specify the Type that is being used and allows the compiler to detect when you are using a collection object in the wrong way.  So for VBA encapsulating data in a collection object is a good way to store data and probably the way you should wish to go.

Comment: Can't help wondering if Power Query might be a better approach to this?

Comment: @androo235 not sure how PowerQuery would be a solution. I ended up with almost 90 files with different layouts. But I worked very little with PowerQuery, tbh